# MVC 6 Custom Taghelper Validation - Solution

Tags: validation, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

Moving from HtmlHelpers I created a few year ago, I have a custom Taghelper that as is marked up during development as so...

```
    <gdropdown asp-for="Type_ID" asp-items="cboType_SelectOne"></gdropdown>
```

All works fine and the output for this is as follows...

```
    <div>
        <select id="Type_ID" name="Type_ID">
            <option value=-1> - Select One - </option>
            <option value=9>Aux. Ext. Device</option>
            <option value=28>Backup Device</option>
            ...
        </select>
    </div>
```

Now I am looking for help crafting my OWN validation SPAN to add to the output as follows...

```
    <div>
        <select id="Type_ID" name="Type_ID">
            <option value=-1> - Select One - </option>
            <option value=9>Aux. Ext. Device</option>
            <option value=28>Backup Device</option>
            ...
        </select>

        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Type_ID">
            <span for="Type_ID">Req!</span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Anyway, I can manage to do the basics of creating that SPAN, however I can't get to the data annotations for the field that is being added/edited.

Using HtmlHelpers I could use htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor() as follows in order to craft the output automatically...

```
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomLookupFor2<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> exp, string url, bool includeValidation, object options)
    {
        ...
        if (includeValidation) sbCtrls.Append(htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression));
        ...
    }
```

From within the TagHelper ProcessAsync method, how can I get to the same or similar data annotation information? Or better still, how can I auto generate the validation element entirely in in a similar fashion as above?

Comment: I don't want to use the Validation TagHelpers. If I am to move to TagHelpers, I want for the main TagHelper for each field to create it's own validation output. Otherwise my code will become more verbose as opposed to more terse.

Comment: why the question has jquery-validate tag ?

Comment: Please do not tag-spam.  Since the question has nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin, do not use this tag.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: My first post on StackOverflow. Apologies if you feel I have mis-represented my query. To be honest I do consider this to be related to that jquery.validate plugin in the sense that I am using that particular technology as part of this solution. It's entirely fundamental to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**** SOLUTION - 13 Mar 2016 ****

You can use the `ModelExpression` passed in via the `asp-for` attribute. More specifically the `modExp.Metadata.ValidatorMetadata` class.

I discovered that the old validation annotation method doesn't work with EF7 yet. At least not in the fashion I am used to.

```
    [MetadataType(typeof(IT_AssetValidation))]
    public partial class IT_Asset
    {
        public class IT_AssetValidation
        {
            [Range(1, 1000000, ErrorMessage = "Req!")]
            public string Product_ID { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Req!")]
            public string Date_Acquired { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

For now, until EF7 supports additional data annotations, I will have to create my annotations (for dev/test purposes only for now) directly in my POCO classes as below. Given I am only using one table to help in the creation of of my new TagHelpers, that's no big bind. Just allows me to get on with developing these TagHelpers ready for when I finally do make the transition to MVC 6, once EF7 is fully functional and settled down a bit.

```
    public partial class IT_Asset
    {
        public int Asset_ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Req!")]
        public DateTime? Date_Acquired { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 1000000, ErrorMessage = "Req!")]
        public int? Product_ID { get; set; }
    }
```

The code for creating my validation `<span data-...></span>` for now will look a little like below.

```
    public static TagBuilder ValidationTag(ModelExpression modExp)
    {
        if ((modExp != null) && (modExp.Metadata.ValidatorMetadata.Count > 0))
        {
            //Construct the HTML span template
            var valTag = new TagBuilder("span");
            valTag.Attributes.Add("class", "");
            valTag.Attributes.Add("data-valmsg-for", modExp.Name);

            return valTag;
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

The code for deriving the validation attributes for the tag that is being validated is as below. This is early pseudo code just now. I will update later perhaps.

```
    public static string ValidationAttributes(ModelExpression modExp)
    {
        if ((modExp != null) && (modExp.Metadata.ValidatorMetadata.Count > 0))
        {
            var ruleAttributes = new StringBuilder();

            //*PSUEDO CODE* Return the rules 
            foreach(...) {
                 If (REQ) ruleAttributes.Append(REQ attribute)
                 If (RANGE) ruleAttributes.Append(RANGE attribute)
                 etc. etc.
            }

            return ruleAttributes.ToString();
        }
        else return "";
    }
```

If anybody knows of a more automatic way of creating the validation tag, and/or deriving the attributes for the tag being validated, than my manual method here, I would be very appreciative.

I will update this solution as my code and understanding develops.